# Run Linux GUI (X) application as another (system, non-root) user

Tags: linux, sudo, su

i am trying to write a custom (GUI) program installer which needs to run as a specific (system) user (without a home directory) - let's call him "installer". Things i have tried or pondered to achieve this in a couple of different ways:

1. launching the GUI installer app as user "installer" through (gk)su(do) (-u). the problem is that a. these commands are not available on every
   distribution or do not behave the same everywhere thanks to internal aliases, and b. the x server does not allow me to connect as a different user without some potentially insecure "xhost +" modification (the old "cannot connect to X server :0.0" problem).
2. avoiding the X server for the installer routine and create a separate (CLI) binary for the chmod/file copy process, while the GUI runs in current user mode. the problem is that i have to give the password to the (sudo -S) command in clear text, which shows up in the logs, so not a good idea either.
3. several command combinations of export display, .Xauthority, xhost and anything i could find on stackoverflow, without much success.

so, what do i actually need?

- a distro-independent, secure way of launching a GUI application as another (non-root, but "/home"-less system) user
- an elegant way of asking the current user for the password of user "installer"
- a solution that does not require the current user to enter the root password first, or install the application as root.

i'd be thankful for any thoughts on the matter.

**[edit]** to clarify, i do not rally want to install new programs into the established linux file structure. The whole setup is this:

1. I have a main program that will be installed by the root. this program can be extended by modules.
2. these modules will be installed into a custom folder (let's call it "/progmodules") which is owned by the "installer" user. the goal is to have authorized users to be able to install new modules, without giving them full root access.
3. any users who want to install new modules should be able to run the installer GUI app, enter the "installer" user password, and then have the files transferred.

Comment: From my expirience of Unix/Linux admin - all vendors who has GUI installers are running from root and let admin decide how to run it. IMHO you will not be successful in your approach and create more confusion to admins who will still use `xauth` / `xhost +` / `ssh -X`

Comment: true, other installers do that. but they usually require root access as they routinely create files in directories that are owned or can only written to by root. my (planned) system does not - see editied original question.